# tcmalloc does not override aligned_alloc?

Tags: gcc, glibc, tcmalloc

Just dropped-in the `tcmalloc` 2.7, but for some reason my new which calls aligned_alloc still goes to glibc.
I've added following to the compiler options `-fno-builtin-memalign -fno-builtin-aligned_alloc -fno-builtin-malloc -fno-builtin-calloc -fno-builtin-realloc -fno-builtin-free -nostdlib` with no visible effect.

Ubuntu 18.04, stock GCC, tcmalloc 2.7

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT001: for some reason `GCC` flag `-flto=8` was causing this behavior, first I was suspecting the `--gc-sections` messing with symbols, but it was proven to be wrong, somehow the `-flto` did the difference. 
 If anyone knows why, you are most welcome to explain it here

Comment: Can you post a backtrace from the point where `aligned_alloc` is called? I suspect it's from `libstdc++`.

Comment: It is, I was stepping into in debugger to see what implementation is called. In any case as I found later, it is `-flto` to blame. jemalloc does not kick in too if this flag is applied (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904726/gcc-flto-fno-builtin-and-custom-function-implementation-of-glibc-functions) Opened issues for both `tcmalloc` and `jemalloc` in their respective repositories on GitHub