# GCC, -flto, -fno-builtin and custom function implementation of glibc functions

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, linkage

I'm observing unexpected behaviour (at least I cant find explanation for it) with GCC flag `-flto` and `jemalloc`/`tcmalloc`. Once `-flto` is used and I link with above libraries malloc/calloc and friends are not replaced by `je/tc malloc` implementation, the glibc implementation is called. Once I remove `-flto` flag, everything works as expected. I tried to use `-fno-builtin`/`-fno-builtin-*` with `-flto` but still, it doesnt pick the `je/tc malloc` implementation.

How the `-flto` machinery works? Why the binary doesnt pick new implementation? How it even links with `-fno-builtin` when it should fail on unresolved external for, say, `printf`?

EDIT001:
GCC 7.3
Sample code

```
int main()
{
    auto p = malloc(1024);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

> /usr/bin/c++    -O2 -g -DNDEBUG   -flto -std=gnu++14 -o
>   CMakeFiles/flto.dir/main.cpp.o -c
>   /home/user/Development/CPPJunk/flto/main.cpp

Linkage:

> /usr/bin/c++  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG  -flto CMakeFiles/flto.dir/main.cpp.o 
>   -o flto  -L/home/user/Development/jemalloc -Wl,-rpath,/home/user/Development/jemalloc -ljemalloc

EDIT002:
More suitable sample code

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    auto p = malloc(1024);
    if (p) {
        free(p);
    }

    auto p1 = new int;
    if (p1) {
        delete p1;
    }

    auto p2 = new int[32];
    if (p2) {
        delete[] p2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post a [mcve], please?

Comment: You didn't give nearly enough details. You should specify the gcc version, command line you're using to build this, and the code which can demonstrate this behavior.

Comment: @Groo you got it

Comment: Did you also compile your `libjemalloc` with `-flto` ?

Comment: nope... Should I? why? I guess, for example, all my `boost` libraries are not compiled with `-flto`...

Answer (score 3):

First, your sample code is wrong. Read carefully the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). When you want to use the *standard* `malloc`, you should `#include <stdlib.h>`.

In C++11 (read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) `malloc` is frowned upon and should not be used (prefer `new`). If you still want to use [`std::malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) in C++ you should `#include <cstdlib>` (which, in GCC, is internally including `<stdlib.h>`)

Then your sample code is almost C code (once you replace `auto` with `void*`), not C++. It could be [optimized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (once you include `<stdlib.h>`), even *without* `-flto` but with just `-O3`, according to the [as-if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) rule, to an empty `main`. (I've even wrote a public report, [bismon-chariot-doc.pdf](https://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf), which has a section §1.4.2 explaining in several pages how that optimization happens).

To optimize around `malloc` and `free`, GCC uses some `__attribute__(malloc)` [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) in the declaration (inside `<stdlib.h>`) of `malloc`.

> How the -flto machinery works?

### LTO is explained in [GCC internals §25](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO.html).

It works by using some internal ([GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html#GIMPLE)-like and/or [SSA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/SSA.html)-like) representation of the code both at "compile" and at "link" time (actually, the linking step becomes another compilation with whole-program optimization, so your code gets "compiled" twice in practice).

LTO *always* should (in practice) be used with some optimization flag (e.g. `-O2` or even `-O3`) both at compile and at link time. So you should compile *and link* with `g++ -flto -O2` (it has no practical sense to use `-flto` *without* at least `-O2` and the *exact same* optimization flags should be used at compile and at link time).

More precisely `-flto` also embeds in the object files some internal ([GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html#GIMPLE)-like) representation of the source code, and that is also used "at link time" (notably for [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) and [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) happening again when "linking" your *entire* program, re-using its GIMPLE). Actually GCC contains some LTO front-end and compiler called `lto1` (in addition of the C++ front-end and compiler called `cc1plus`) and `lto1` is (when you *link* with `g++ -flto -O2`) used at link time to reprocess these GIMPLE representations.

Probably, `libjemalloc` has its own headers, and might have `inline`  (or inlinable) functions. Then you also need to use `-flto -O2` when compiling that library from its source code (so that its Gimple is stored in the library)

At last, the fact that the usual `malloc` gets called is independent of `-flto`. It is a linker issue, not a compiler one. You could try to link `-ljemalloc` statically (and then you'll better build that library also with `gcc -flto -O2`; if you don't build it like that you won't get LTO optimizations across `malloc` calls).

You could pass also `-v` to your compilation and linking commands to understand what `g++` is doing. You could even pass `-Wl,--verbose` to ask the `ld` (started by `g++`) to be verbose.

Notice that LTO (and the internal representations that it is using) is compiler and version specific. The internal (Gimple & [SSA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/SSA.html)) representation is *slightly* different between [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) & [GCC 8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/) (and in Clang it is *very* different, so of course incompatible). The dynamic linker [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) does not know about LTO.

PS. You could install the `libjemalloc-dev` package and add `#include <jemalloc/jemalloc.h>` in your code. See also [jemalloc(3)](http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html) man page. Probably `libjemalloc` could be configured or patched to define some `je_malloc` symbol as a replacement for `malloc`. Then it would be simpler (for LTO) to use `je_malloc` in your code (to avoid conflict between several `malloc` [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) symbols). To learn more about symbols in shared libraries, read Drepper's [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper. And of course you should expect LTO to change the behavior of linking!

Comment: But what is the deal with linker? why `-flto` affects the linkage of `jemalloc` into my executable and how to solve this issue?

Comment: That would be a different question. Maybe you could link `libjemalloc` statically. And I don't think that it is worth using in 2018. Recent GNU glibc had made considerable progress on `malloc`. However, to take real advantage of LTO, *all* the code that matters to you should be built with `-flto -O2` (and that includes libraries!)

Comment: Define 'recent'. I'm on ubuntu 18.04, `jemalloc` improved application performance by ~15%. But yes, I'm trying not to use external allocator libraries, since I believe C RTL should provide good enough memory management, which is almost always true. Unfortunately not in this very specific case.

Comment: Already tried -v, not too enlightening, will try -Wl,--verbose now

Comment: My guess is that you should build `libjemalloc.a` with `gcc -flto -O2` and link that `libjemalloc.a` explicitly. Any LTO optimization needs the Gimple of called functions.

Comment: If I rebuild `jemalloc` with `-flto`, do I have to link statically? Why `so` wouldnt make the trick?

Comment: Because the dynamic linker (`ld-linux.so`) does not know about LTO

Comment: Ok, will try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185723/discussion-between-kreuzerkrieg-and-basile-starynkevitch).